# How to recover deleted/updated records in Informix?

Tags: sql, informix, data-recovery

I want to know if there's any way to recover the deleted or updated records updated accidentally in an Informix DB?

The table structure is like this:

```
ID  NAME  CODE
1   john   yy7
2   Rany   uu6
3   Mike   hh7
```

The data has been updated to:

```
ID  NAME  CODE
1   XX   yy7
2   XX   uu6
3   XX   hh7
```

Comment: Ask your DBA to restore a back-up.

Comment: @jarlh : the last backup is a little earlier

Comment: And no db logging?

Comment: @jarlh : is there any automatic log in `informix` because i don't think i have manual log

Comment: You need to find out whether your database was created 'WITH LOG' or not.  A simple test is: can you run BEGIN WORK successfully. (If it works, add a ROLLBACK WORK.)  If your DB was created with a log, then there may be ways to recover the data.  If not, the data is gone.  Do consult with your DBA quickly.  The longer you leave it, the harder it is to recover.  Recovery is not straight-forward. Even with logs, there are many things that could prevent recovery.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Could You help me how to know if my DB created with log or not please ?

Comment: I told you how to do it.  Try to start a transaction; if it fails, your DB is unlogged. If it works, there's an outside chance that you may be able to recover the data.  Which version of Informix are you using, and on which platform?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :`IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC3`

Comment: `informix client SDK version : 3.50`

Comment: Curious. You're using an old CSDK with a new server.  The current CSDK version is 4.10 (you'll skip 3.70). Platform (meaning operating system)?   If you have access to `dbaccess` you can check the DB logging status with that. Or use `onstat`. Your server is recent and a 64-bit version.

Comment: If you created the DB and didn't ensure it has logging, it will be unlogged. That's the default for historical reasons, though there might now be a way to override that default.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Could i ask if the log has the same DB schema . i mean creating log table for each table ? or just a flat table

Comment: Your choice of terminology suggests that you're new to Informix. I'd go for chat except I'm on the app and walking the dog.

Comment: The log doesn't have a schema per se. It records all changes made to all the databases in the instance of Informix. It exists whether a database within the instance is logged or not. However, if the DB is logged, information about before and after images of rows are stored so that the system can be recovered up to the last commit (and uncommitted changes rolled back).  If your DB is logged, it might be possible to do some sort of point-in-time recovery to just before the faulty changes were made, but it is a delicate operation and much more info about backups etc will be required.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :Really thank u so much for your help :ٍD

Comment: The more activity that occurs on the system (in any of the databases), the harder it will be to recover. Are you using a 'tenant database' by any chance?  The chances are if you don't know, you aren't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : I don't think so :D

Comment: Pity about it not being a tenant database. Are you the DBA too?  If so, you may be able to get help from the IBM/Informix tech support team. Otherwise, it is time to start planning on your way forward, regenerating the data as best you can (maybe recover your latest archives into a new instance and export what you had from that 'temporary' instance back to your main one). You need to ensure your database is logged, and that you have a (tested) backup and restore system. Consider looking at the [IIUG web site](http://www.iiug.org/) and its mailing lists.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : No, I'm not a DBA.just want to help the DBA in my team to solve the problem .we intend to migrate from `informix` to `Oracle` or `sqlserver` as soon as possible

Comment: As to deleted rows, is there a way to undelete them by removing the null flags since those rows are still physically in the table?